# Is there a way to test toast messages in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, integration-testing, flutter-test

Is there a way to get the test driver to see the toast messages on the screen in an integration test in flutter?

I used **find.byText** and added a delay to the test but it didn't work.

Any work around this?

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit more?

Comment: If you are using [`fluttertoast`](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast) package, this is [issue](https://github.com/ponnamkarthik/FlutterToast/issues/262)

Comment: Yes, it seems there's no way to find fluttertoast with find.type checking the GitHub issue [FlutterToast/issues/262] (https://github.com/ponnamkarthik/FlutterToast/issues/262)